# file not found exception while reading from properties

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I am facing below error while reading the ost_file_path from `emailconfig.cfg`, the config file is read using property load, but when i hardcode the file , it has no issues in reading the file.

### Exception received

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: "C:\Users\gcothak2\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\gopala.cothakotai@credit-suisse.com - Default Outlook Profile.ost" (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:241)
    at com.pff.PSTFile.<init>(PSTFile.java:125)
    at com.pff.PSTFile.<init>(PSTFile.java:119)
    at com.test.programs.EmailReadProcess.EmailReadExecute(EmailReadProcess.java:86)
    at com.test.programs.EmailReadProcess.main(EmailReadProcess.java:75)
```

### Manual hardcode of ost_file_path

```
//String filename  = "C:\\Users\\gcothak2\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Outlook\\gopala.cothakotai@credit-suisse.com - Default Outlook Profile.ost";
```

### EmailConfig.cfg

```
FOLDERS_TO_SEARCH = "Inbox|SDO"

SUBJECT_TO_SEARCH = "^CLOCK CONTRACT FILE$"

OST_FILE_PATH = 

    "C:\\Users\\gcothak2\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Outlook\\gopala.cothakotai\@debit-base.com - Default Outlook Profile.ost"

FOLDERS_SEPARATOR_DELIM = "|"

RERUN_ONCE_AGAIN = true

TIME_TO_RUN = 16:00

ATTACHMENT_DOWNLOAD_PATH = "M:\\tempReports" 

RERUN_ONCE_AGAIN=true
```

**EmailReadProcess.java**

```
public void readFromConfig(String filename) throws Exception {

    //path of the class file
    String filepath = EmailReadProcess.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();

    //String filepath = "M:\\Documents\\workspace-sts-3.7.0.RELEASE\\LDODashBoard\\target\\classes";

    //path of the config file
    configFilename = filename;

    props.load(new FileInputStream(filepath + "\\"+ configFilename));

    //it will be separated by pile delimited
    foldersToSearch = props.getProperty("FOLDERS_TO_SEARCH");
    subjectToSearch = props.getProperty("SUBJECT_TO_SEARCH");
    ostFilepath = props.getProperty("OST_FILE_PATH");
    foldersSearchDelim = props.getProperty("FOLDERS_SEPARATOR_DELIM");

    System.out.println("filepath:"  + filepath);
    System.out.println("configFilename:"  + configFilename);



    System.out.println("foldersSearchDelim:"  + foldersSearchDelim);

    if (props.getProperty("RERUN_ONCE_AGAIN").equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
        rerunOnceAgain = true;
    }
    else{
        rerunOnceAgain = false;
    }

    //eg: 16:00 or 09:01 
    timeToRun = props.getProperty("TIME_TO_RUN");
    attachDownloadPath = props.getProperty("ATTACHMENT_DOWNLOAD_PATH");

    foldersInList = convertFoldersToList();
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //String filename  = "C:\\Users\\gcothak2\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Outlook\\gopala.cothakotai@credit-suisse.com - Default Outlook Profile.ost";
    //new EmailReadProcess(args[0]);

    String filename = "TSEEmailconfig.cfg";
    EmailReadProcess emailProcess = new EmailReadProcess();

    try {
        emailProcess.readFromConfig(filename);
        emailProcess.EmailReadExecute();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void EmailReadExecute() {
    try {
        //ostFilepath = "C:\\Users\\gcothak2\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Outlook\\gopala.cothakotai@credit-suisse.com - Default Outlook Profile.ost";
        PSTFile pstFile = new PSTFile(ostFilepath);
        System.out.println(pstFile.getMessageStore().getDisplayName());
        processFolder(pstFile.getRootFolder());
    } catch (Exception err) {
        err.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you try with a file name without spaces ?

Comment: Try to escape white spaces with `\ ` like you did for `@`

Comment: Did the double quotes actually end up as part of the filename? You don't need quotes in property files. `System.out.println` exactly what the filename looks like.

Comment: BTW, in your given `EmailConfig.cfg` the ost file URL is different from exception

Comment: space should not be the problem the reason the hard code value also contains space                                                                                                        //String filename  = "C:\\Users\\gcothak2\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Outlook\\gopala.cothakotai@credit-suisse.com - Default Outlook Profile.ost";

Comment: The issues as resolved, actually no issue with the coding, it just closed and opened the outlook which started working..